# Load an image into QGIS by clicking on a vector footprint

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, imagery

I have a shapefile with image footprints. Each footprint/shape contains links (both local and web) to the georeferenced image it represents. 
Is there any way to load an image into QGIS when user clicks on a corresponding shape?

Comment: please clarify if you want to be able to look at these images using qgis (e.g. 'identify features' button) or maybe to export the map with these images above the map

Comment: Done. Actually this is a part of a workflow I'm trying to implement as a plugin

Comment: do you need load image with a pop-up in canvas?where you need load,in qgis or in a external web?

Comment: I'd like to load it as a raster layer on top of a map